# Converting "form_tag" to "form_for" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a form tag that calls a controller and a method. I'm new to form helpers and I would like to change this form_tag to say the same thing just simply be a form_for

FORM_TAG:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "subscribers", action: "visit"}, method: "get") do %>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @subscriber = Subscriber.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def search
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def visit
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
    if @subscriber
      @subscriber.visit ||= 0
      @subscriber.visit += 1
      @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = flash[:notice] = "Thank You #{@subscriber.first_name}. You have #{@subscriber.days_till_expired} until renewal"
      redirect_to subscribers_info_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "search"
    end
  end

  def info
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
  end
```

I think this is enough info let me know if you need more? Thank you!

Comment: so what have you tried so far? what part of translation to `form_for` seems complicated?

Comment: Do you have a @subscriber object when you render `form_for`?

Comment: Well, The part where the controller is being called in the hash

Comment: @Leito I think you're right! that's why it's a form for I believe

Comment: Can I give two actions to a form tag?

Comment: try form_for(url: visit_subscribers_path, html: { method: :get })